# Elasticsearch - sort based on cosine similarity of float arrays

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to sort based on the Cosine similarity of two different float arrays? Similar to how you can sort by geo distance by passing a coordinate to sort?

Answer (score 1):

I is possible if one the arrays is an input, but you will have to implement the cosine similarity as a script:

```
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "source": """
      def vector = params._source[params.vector_field];
      def dot_product = 0.0;
      def v_norm = 0.0;
      for (int i = 0; i < params.query_vector.length; ++i) { 
          def x = vector[i]; 
          dot_product += x * params.query_vector[i]; 
          v_norm += x * x;
      }
      return v_norm > 0 ? dot_product / (params.query_v_norm * Math.sqrt(v_norm)) : -1;
"""
  }
```

However this uses the field `source`, which can be slow. [See this other question to make it faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57211362/how-to-convert-binary-data-back-to-a-float-array-in-elasticsearch-painless)

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for elastic search open distro (open search) version 7.6.1:

```
GET jobsearch_v20/_search
{
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "script_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": """
        // def vector = params._source[params.field];
        def vector = [1,2,3]
        def dot_product = 0.0;
        def val_norm = 0.0;
        def vec_norm = 0.0;
        for (int i =0; i< params.query_value.length; ++i){
          def x = vector[i];
          dot_product += x * params.query_value[i];
          val_norm += x * x;
          vec_norm += params.query_value[i] * params.query_value[i];
          
        }
        return val_norm > 0 ? dot_product / (Math.sqrt(vec_norm) * Math.sqrt(val_norm)) : -1;
        """,
        "params": {
          "field": "vector",
          "query_value": [
            3,
            4,
            5
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please replace query value with the vector input and uncomment the commented line after source to run it. It will score the similarity between two vectors.